# How to avoid embedded MongoDb download with Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, spring-boot

In my project, I am using spring-boot and embedded Mongo Db, see my pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.default</groupId>
    <artifactId>default</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>default</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <version>1.50.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.8</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>
                        -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
                    </jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Application</mainClass>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <copy file="${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config.txt"
                                    tofile="${project.basedir}/target/classes/infra/config.txt" />
                                <copy file="${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config.txt"
                                    tofile="${project.basedir}/target/config.txt" />
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

When I run "mvn spring-boot:run" at first time my maven start download MongoDB binaries, in development environment it's ok, but when I run the jar project (generated by mvn clean install) using "java -jar" I see another download started for MongoDB binaries.

So ... to avoid this download when I run using "java -jar" I would like to insert MongoDB binaries in my project jar.

Is it possible?

Tks guys.

Comment: Take the `de.flapdoodle.embed` out of the project for production builds. All it does is downloads the server binaries.

Comment: When I will run this project on production environment I can't start download MongoDB binaries, but I need to start an instance of embedded  MongoDB without downloading any code from the web.

Comment: You can like whatever you want, but that's not how you do it. MongoDB is something that should be installed "separately". That dependency I just highlighted is just a package that downloads and runs MongoDB for your environment in "testing". It's not your application's job to do that in production. Databases typically live on different machines to your code. If you are looking for an "embedded database", then that is not it.

Comment: Neil, you are correct, but in this case, I will use MongoDB like as cache to save net traffic, the "hot" data was stored on another machine (Oracle)

Comment: The embedded make sense only for testing, you should add the `<scope>test</scope>` to your `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo` dependency

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the mongo dependency from `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
               <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Tks Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn, but I need to start an embedded  MongoDB Instance.

When I will run this project on production environment I can't start download MongoDB binaries, I would like to start this instance from a jar stored in my project.

Comment: Add a maven dependency for your mongo, scope is "provided"

Comment: But if I use "provided" in a production environment I can't start the DB engine.